# Are there Algorithms for generating textures using vector primitives?

Tags: algorithm, canvas, graphics, 2d

I'm doing image generation with Canvas, for fun and I'd like to generate textures using canvas alone.  That is I'd like to stay just in canvas and generate paper, stone, sand, wood textures.  I've tried but they tend to remain vector looking.  But, I'm wondering if there are algorithms that I could look at to help me design some textures?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found decent algorithms for "organic" textures.

Good looking vectors are often extremely complex to reflect the complexity of the "real thing".

If you want to experiment:

- download a trial version of Adobe Illustrator,
- open a basic texture image,
- run the "trace" procedure which turns the raster image into vector pieces,
- export the vector pieces as canvas drawing commands using a plug-in (eg: http://drawscri.pt/ )
- experiment!